# Why does resizable() act differently for an image than it does for a div?

Tags: html, jquery-ui

I notice that resizable() treats an img differently than a div.  You can can see this at http://jsfiddle.net/stevea/yW8NZ/3/ . When you resize the div, resizable()just adds the handle after the div.

```
<div id="box" class="ui-resizable">
    <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-se ui-icon ui-icon-gripsmall-diagonal-se" style="z-  index: 1000;"></div>
</div>
```

When you resize the image, resizable() changes the img display from inline to block, adds the handle after it,  and then puts a ui-wrapper around the image and the handle:

```
<div class="ui-wrapper" style="overflow: hidden; position: relative; width: 100px; height: 79px; top: 0px; left: 0px; margin: 0px;">
    <img id="cateye" class="ui-resizable" src="http://s20.postimg.org/ddh45wqnd/t_cateye.jpg" style="resize: none; position: static; display: block; height: 79px; width: 100px;">
    <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-se ui-icon ui-icon-gripsmall-diagonal-se" style="z-index: 1000;"></div>
</div>
```

Does someone understand why this different treatment is necessary?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [fine `<img>` specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/img.html#img-content-model):

> **Permitted contents**
>
> Empty (void element)

You can't put *anything* inside an `<img>` so, in particular, you can't put the handle `<div>` inside the `<img>`. So, jQuery-UI tightly wraps the `<img>` with a `<div>` so that it can put the handle somewhere.

---

Interestingly enough, if you set up a resizable `<span>`, jQuery-UI will put the handle `<div>` inside the `<span>` even though that's invalid HTML. A [`<span>` can contain](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/span.html) phrasing content, phrasing content consists of phrasing elements and character data (i.e. text); if we look at what [phrasing elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/common-models.html#common.elem.phrasing) are, you won't find `<div>` in that list, a `<div>` is a [flow element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/common-models.html#common.elem.flow), not a phrasing element.

I'd call that a bug in jQuery-UI, they really should be using a `<span>` for the handle since you can, AFAIK, put a `<span>` inside anything that allows children. OTOH, certain parts of the spec are handled more strictly than others in real life so this probably doesn't break out in the real world.